# Boat children and army crossing the river puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, story, river-crossing

During the war, a small detachment found itself
confronted by a deep and wide river. However, they found a small boat in which
two-children were rowing about. It was a very small boat and can only carry the
2-children, or one grown person with it.
How did the captain get himself and his 357 other soldiers across the river and leave
the two-children finally in joint possession of their boat? And how many times
need the boat pass from shore to shore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get one grown person across as follows

> The two children row across.
>  One child rows back.
>  The grown person rows across.
>  The other child rows back.

To generalise this to the captain and 357 soldiers

> Just repeat the above procedure 358 times.

The boat passes shore to shore a total of

> 1432 times

Answer (score 0):

If the boys and their boat are initially on the opposite shore to the 358 men, then, for each man:

> 1. One boy rows across
>
>  2. One man rows across
>
>  3. The other boy rows across
>
>  4. Both boys row across

which is just a cyclic permutation of hexomino's answer. After

> 357*4+2=1430

trips, all 358 men have now crossed, as required. Granted, the boys are now on opposite shores, but it wasn't required to return them both to one particular shore.